# is there a remote software with one time link for my clients?

Tags: software-testing, remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-control

I am looking for a type of software for a specfiic use case. Is there a software that can email my clients a link or a one time code to remote in to my setup workstation/computer? The simpler this software the better. I just want to simply install the software on a computer and when my clients ask access I want to send them a link that allows them to access my computer through their browser for that one session(if they have to download an application themselves it's not a deal breaker but not preferred). It would also work if its a software and one time code or something of the sort. The only thing that is the most important is that they can only access this computer for one session. I do not want them to have continued access. Just the once that they request it.

I don't have time to develop this software, this is simply for testing purposes and don't want to put in too much time. it doesn't have to be free but the cheaper the better.

I know about google remote access and other tools like team viewer but they allow the user continues access and user need to register there. I would like the software to not need registration and just use a one time link or code.

Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/) seems to do exactly what you are looking for. You would just have to install a Chrome extension to allow others to connect to your computer, and there is no need to install anything from the client side, assuming they are already using a Google Chrome browser. You can generate a random one-time code that you can send to someone else, and they can only use that code once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cloud-based remote desktop software [Getscreen.me](https://getscreen.me/) The remote connection is made from the browser through a link that is sent to the user. After the session ends, access is closed. There is a possibility of permanent access, but for this you need to bind the computer and install the agent.

But if you just need a quick connection via a one-time link, your computer won't be permanently accessible. You can test the service with a demo version, we will be grateful for feedback.

P.S. I am a person affiliated with Getscreen.me.